# Eclipse : Starting tomcat server from eclipse , does not start the deployed wars

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-wtp

I have configured Tomcat Server in Eclipse Helios IDE , and 
started the server in Debug Mode .

This Server has already  got a war file probe.war .

My question is,why this application probe.war has not been started when i started the Server from Eclipse IDE ??

This is the  server console  eclipse under the Eclipse IDE .

```
Oct 22, 2011 12:31:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.32
Oct 22, 2011 12:31:57 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Oct 22, 2011 12:31:57 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Oct 22, 2011 12:31:57 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/47  config=null
Oct 22, 2011 12:31:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 401 ms
```

Comment: I think you've manually put the war in the `webapps` directory, but Eclipse configures a different one. Are you using [WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/)?

Comment: Yes , you are correct , i manually put that probe.war which has not been started . How will WTP will be useful in this case ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WTP offers integration between Eclipse and Tomcat, if you're not using it, you're more on your own.

As you said in the comment, you've manually placed the war file, but since you're starting Tomcat with Eclipse, the `webapps` directory configured  by Eclipse is not the same one you're using, so your application doesn't get deployed.

To solve your problem either:

- configure your application properly, so you can right click on it and choose `Debug As` -> `Debug on server`
- or, configure it externally, by [following the steps to debug a remote tomcat application](http://en.newinstance.it/2005/10/04/remote-debugging-tomcat-with-eclipse/), and start your tomcat server from the command line, so your war will get deployed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , you provided , can you please confirm the steps i followed is correct or not . 
i have got project inside eclipse IDE , by running the  maven script it creates a war and deployed it in tomcat webapps .

I started the Tomcat server by executing the startup.exe 
Now inside the  Eclipse IDE (Run -->DebugConfigurations --New Remote Java Appliction-->
Provided the port -- , server and source .

But i am getting 

Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection timed out.
org.eclipse.jdi.TimeoutException 

Please tell me if this is correct or not ??

Comment: And you put localhost right, have you checked if you can connect to the port with telnet? Or you've a couple of other options with Maven. Delete the project from Eclipse, including `.settings/`, `.classpath` and `.project`. From the command line you can run `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, then choose from Eclipse File, Import, General, `Existing Project into workspace`, now you can use WTP and use the simpler first option. Or install m2eclipse plugin, plus m2eclipse WTP support and after removing and cleaning the project choose Import, Maven, `Existing Maven Projects`.

Comment: Yes i have provided the port and serer values correctly and i can connect to the http:localhost:8080 from browser . Yes before trying with Maven Plugin , i wanted to solve this . please see the screen shots   http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=262uom0&s=7 , http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=fns743&s=7 , http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=ymf6a&s=7

Comment: before trying with Maven Plugin , just wanted to know will the above approach is corect or not ??

Comment: I'm sorry the URL I gave you is not OK for your case of debugging with Tomcat 6. Let me try, I will message you back soon.

Comment: [Try here](http://en.newinstance.it/2005/10/04/remote-debugging-tomcat-with-eclipse/). The port you've to connect to is not 8080 as you shown in the picture, but the port you specify for the debugger!

Comment: Thanks for the link , i have done these steps , please tell me if its correct or not ,  I have set these inside the System Environment variables
JPDA_ADDRESS
5050
JPDA_TRANSPORT
dt_socket
And then started in this command prompt 
Please see this screen shot.
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2hncpwh&s=7

Comment: Why if the instructions tells you to run catalina, you run tomcat instead?

Comment: Ya , i did that i am pasting the command prompt console                    C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\bin>tomcat6.exe jpda start
[2011-10-22 21:11:39] [warn]  No service name provided
[2011-10-22 21:11:39] [error] Load configuration failed
[2011-10-22 21:11:39] [error] The system could not find the environment option that was entered.
[2011-10-22 21:11:39] [error] Commons Daemon procrun failed with exit value: 2 (Failed to load configuration)
[2011-10-22 21:11:39] [error] The system could not find the environment option that was entered.

Comment: Please see this screen shot when i gave catilna , i got this error http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=a44plk&s=7  , so i gave tomcat6

Comment: I am using Tomcat6 and i have only these under the bin folder http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2r2yv46&s=7

Comment: I've just downloaded the latest 6.x version of Tomcat for windows 64 bit to check and it's there.
`$ unzip -l apache-tomcat-6.0.33-windows-x64.zip  | grep catalina.bat` :
`11830  2011-08-16 14:25   apache-tomcat-6.0.33/bin/catalina.bat`

Comment: I downloaded apache-tomcat-6.0.33 and i found all those components , let me try and will  let you know