# GWT project external mode Main/Main.nocache.js not found

Tags: maven, tomcat, gwt, publish

i'm working with GWT and runnin on apache tomcat 7.0.16, when today i tried to start application and i got an error when browser opened. in browser console 404 Main/Main.nocache.js. what can i fix it.

when i looked at org.eclipse.wsr.server.core/temp0/wtpwebapps directory cant see Main directory and their content such as nocache.js and other static content.

and i checked eclipse war directory Main directory is exist.

i think some configurations has changed and tomcat cant publish.

my gwt module name is "Main"

thanks for reply.

good hacking.....

Answer (score 2):

i solved with gwt run configuration. i work with target dir with target\PROJECT_NAME-SNAPSHOT.0.0.1\ , i worked up to 2 days before. after i got error when i asked below.

Solved with:
GWT run conf.

-war wokspace_classpath\PROJECT_NAME\src\main\webapp